Questions about surface representation by 2n-gon with edges identified in pairs
Suppose we are given a $2n$-gon with the edges identified in pairs, say $a_1a_2...a_na_1^{-1}a_2^{-1}...a_{n-1}^{-1}a_n$.
(1) By drawing the pictures for several values of $n$ and seeing the pattern, I know it has 1 vertex, n edges, and 1 face. However, I am not sure on how to prove this rigorous except by saying, "The initial point of $a_1$ is identified with the terminal point of $a_2^{-1}$, which is identified with the initial point of $a_3$, and so on." Is there a way to prove this rigorous, or is that not necessary? Most proofs I read just say, "After identification, it has $1$ vertex."
(2) Is there a general algorithm for finding the number of vertices besides drawing the picture and identifying points?
(3) I know that surface will be oriented if it has no twisted edges pairs, which is when a pair of edges appear as $a,...,a$ or $a^{-1},...,a^{-1}$. However, I can't intuitively see how it relates to the geometric meaning of oriented, which is when you can color each sides of the surface in different colors and the colors will match up when edges are pasted together.
(4) This question is a little unrelated, but is there also a classification of compact, connected 2-manifolds with boundaries? If so, what are they and how would I calculate its orientability, Euler characteristic, or number of genus? How about if one of the quantifiers, either compactness or connectedness, is removed?

Draw a path from the middle of an edge labeled $a$ to the middle of an edge labeled $a^{-1}$. Since these edges are identified, this path is actually a loop. Now draw an arrow sticking out of a point $x$ on this loop (in a normal direction) and "push" the arrow along the loop until you're back at $x$. It should now be pointing the opposite direction.

Please ask one question per post.

I'll answer question (1). It is easy enough to formalize the identification of vertices using basic concepts of equivalence relations. It helps greatly to first name your individual vertices, perhaps using some naming scheme with subscripts. Then define an "edge gluing relation" $v \sim w$, meaning that there exists an edge pair which, when glued, identifies $v$ with $w$. This relation is already symmetric. Now take the smallest equivalence relation generated by the edge gluing relation. Since your relation is already symmetric, that amounts to simply taking the transitive closure: $v$ is equivalent to $w$ if and only if there exists a sequence of edge gluing relations $v=v_0 \sim v_1 \sim \ldots \sim v_n=w$. The equivalence classes of this relation are, precisely, the vertices of the quotient space.
To summarize this in your own words: Draw the picture and identify the points.

This works when $n$ is chosen (for example $n=5$). But I was wondering if there is a way to prove it when $n$ is arbitrary and we cannot draw the picture?

The "summary" is only meant to appeal to intuition. If you don't want to do that, then you can work instead with the "gluing word". Your example has a gluing word $a_1a_2...a_na_1^{-1}a_2^{-1}...a_n^{-1}$. You can work out the equivalence relation in my answer for any gluing word: list the vertices; write down the edge gluing relation; compute the equivalence classes.
